# How can I refactor duplicated codes for error?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling

I'm using block for my APIs and the API class throws error via block like below code.

```
[HJHLifeAPI deletePlantWithIdentifier:identifier completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        [[error alertView] show];
        return ;
    }

    [self refresh:self.refreshControl];
}];
```

But the problem is that I use this pattern of codes in several places. As a result, I should write several duplicated codes for error handling. Is there any way to refactor this code? I think exception can be one solution, but I think Apple don't encourage developers to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to How your HJHLifeAPI is designed.

I usually use AFNetworking for API things and here's an example.

```
// This is the method like deletePlantWithIdentifier:
// It actually invoke __requestWitPath:
- (void)requestSomethingWithId:(NSString *)memId done:(NetDoneBlock)done
{
    NSMutableDictionary *param_ = @{@"key":@"id"};
    [self __requestWithPath:@"/apiPath.jsp" parameter:param_ done:done];
}


#pragma PRIVATE
- (void)__requestWithPath:(NSString *)apiPath parameter:(NSDictionary *)parameter done:(NetDoneBlock)done
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SERVER_URL]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:apiPath parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            done();
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            // Error Handle Here
    }];

   [operation start];
}
```

You can handle all errors in one `__request...`.

Answer (score 0):

Create the block

```
void(^errorHandler)(NSError *error) = ^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        [[error alertView] show];
        return ;
    }

    [self refresh:self.refreshControl];
}
```

Save it somewhere (don't forget to [copy it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html))

```
self.errorHandler = errorHandler;
```

Reuse it everywhere:

```
[HJHLifeAPI deletePlantWithIdentifier:identifier completionHandler:self.errorHandler];
```